# How does the asyncData function work in NuxtJs?

Tags: javascript, async-await, nuxt.js

I am working on a NuxtJs project and I am fetching some data from our CMS.
I have noticed both of the following calls work but I cannot understand their difference. The first uses 'async' and 'await' whereas the second doesn't. What is, in practice, the difference when I add async and await?

```
async asyncData () {
    const data = await CMS.get.data.getList()
    return {
      data
    }
},
```

```
asyncData () {
    return CMS.get.data.getList().then((res) => {
      return {
        data: res

      }
    })
},
```

Comment: async/await has nothing to do with asyncData(), async/await is a syntax sugar for handling promises. You would otherwise chain .then() to a function that returns a promise. Please take a look at the MDN docs -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Yeah thanks, I am reading about this. I was very confused (and still a bit) with the different ways to deal with asynchronous.

Comment: I think it might be a little too much of overkill to go with a framework like Nuxt if you don't exactly understand asynchronous programming. I don't know your experience level so take this with a grain of salt. A lot of new developers jump into frameworks because they're popular but honestly shouldn't, start from the basics and get good at it. Because frameworks like Nuxt are for complex production-grade products, they abstract a lot of stuff so we can just not focus on them.

I can also recommend you to take a look at javascript.info and a book called YDKJS.

Comment: @CoodleNoodle expecially universal mode is complex for beginners because sometimes  you cannot access DOM elements because it gets serveside rendered and newbies does not know that